# Agregar html en todas las paginas

Tags: javascript, html

para no tener que estar navegando entre páginas no  y tener que estar haciendo cambios en cada una de ellas hice lo siguiente. hice un archivo .js y agregue lo siguiente

```js
document.getElementById('cover').innerHTML +=
  `<div class="cover-empresa-contenedor">
    <figure class="omt-04">
      <img src="/img/cover/cover.jpg" alt="perfil"/>
      <figcaption>
        <img src="/img/logo/logo-muestra.png" class="profile"/>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div> `;
```

Luego en el html simplemente coloco un div con el id cover y por supuesto enlazo el js antes de body como

```js
<script src="/cover.js"></script>
```

Lo que quisiera saber es si esta es la manera correcta de hacerlo o funciona pero no es correcta...Gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta solo puede ser respuesta en base a opiniones y eso va en contra de las normas del sitio, probablemente será cerrada. Por otro lado, hacer esto implica que los motores de búsqueda como google, puntuarán bajo la web porque los bots que usan, no suelen usar javascript para navegar, así que nunca verán el contenido.

Comment: Tu lógica no es equivocada, más bien lo es la herramienta que deseas emplear para conseguir ese objetivo.
Lo que deseas hacer ya viene ampliamente usado en las aplicaciones web para evitar la repetición del código y es especialmente útil a la hora de efectuar una modifica que debe ser reflejada en muchas páginas y así evitar modificarlas manualmente de una en una.
El problema con javascript es que no todos lo tienen activado y esto puede causar que esa parte de tu código no sea visible en la web, aun así si se trata de un contenido que no es relevante podría ser factible.

Comment: Si consideras que es una característica necesaria te recomiendo utilizar un framework, prácticamente todos los que conozco son capases de realizar esta tarea sin necesidad de javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Si no tienes problemas cambiando la extención de tus html a php puedes probar lo siguiente:

Creas el archivo html con el contenido que deseas editar y renombras por ejemplo tu `index.html` a `index.php`, luego...

```
contenido.html
<?php include("contenido.html"); ?>
```

Esto aparte que carga tu contenido en la página web, lo hace `del lado del servidor`, y no hace que el navegador cargue más contenido javascrip.

Comment: @BetaM, por eso dije "Si no tienes problemas cambiando la extención de tus html a php", si para el eso es un problema, entonces no aplica, en mi caso es como resuelvo el incrustar menus, footer y otros en mis sitios web. Todos los servidores soportan PHP, no significa que tenga que trasladar su lenguaje HTML a php, solamente la extención del archivo.

Answer (score 0):

El código que empleas con HTML y JS está bien, sin embargo este se aplica al momento de cargar la página, lo que siempre se prefiere es que esté en el servidor, si usas javascript, los motores de búsqueda no tendrán buen efecto al momento de encontrar tu página. Si no tienes la disponibilidad de usar PHP o algún tipo de lenguaje de programación del lado del servidor utiliza un framework como [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/)

Si tienes la disponibilidad de usar PHP, crea un archivo que HTML que contenga lo que quieres añadir a cada página (No incluyas `<! DOCTYPE HTML>`), después deberás poner `<?php require("nombre.html"); ?>` (Cambia nombre.html con el nombre que le pusiste a el archivo) esto si pondrá todos los contenidos del lado del servidor correctamente.

Ten en cuenta que los archivos PHP no se ejecutan sin un servidor, puedes usar un servidor para generar localhost, un programa muy completo para esto es [laragon](https://laragon.org/)

Comment: Excelente Gracias amigo